# iPhone - How to add people to on-going video chat in Facebook messenger?

Tags: ios, facebook

I'm using an iPhone 7 running iOS 12.

When I'm in an on-going video chat, I can't find the "add people" button to add more people to the on-going video chat. In Android I can see that button just fine, so I'm surprised that iOS doesn't have it.

Do I need to activate it via settings or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. It's not the iPhone's fault, it's the fault of the other phone which uses [Messenger Lite](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facebook.mlite). Messenger Lite doesn't have conference call feature (at this moment). So if [Messenger (full version)](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/messenger/id454638411?mt=8) calls Messenger Lite, the "add people" button isn't available. So I install [Messenger (full version)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facebook.orca) for the other phone and try calling again, and now I can see the "add people" button.

[image: Conference call feature on Messenger (full version)]